# Tutorials on Creating Demoscenes

Tags: demoscene

### Context:

- Watch: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWcbj7ksqwE
- I'm familiar with OpenGL / GLSL / C++ / C
- I've done some audio programming.

  Never mind trying to compress it down to 64k or 4k for the moment.

  I don't even know how to procedurally synthesize something like the above demo.

### Question:

I realize the demoscene is somewhat of an underground blackart. However, is there any good tutorials / walkthroughs on creating one of these? Something like:

"Demoscene for Dummies that know OpenGL / GLSL / C++ / C"

I also realize there are toolkits designed to compress down the code -- however for me compression is not important at the moment. I would be happy to merely learn how to create something like this.

### Concise Question:

Can anyone suggest a good tutorial / walkthrough on creating a demo scene step by step, for someone with enough of a technical background to understand the individual steps (but yet unable to see the whole picture).

Thanks.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a link to a pdf written by the programmer behind the technical magic.  It's a really great read.

http://www.iquilezles.org/www/material/function2009/function2009.pdf

His site itself is a treasure trove of information regarding demoscene programming techniques.

I wrote a 4k demo which won 1st place at an Australian demoscene party (Syntax)... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t7anicyRI3w

Comment: +1 for the link and congrats :)

Comment: The URL for the  writeup has been slightly changed moved, you can now find it here: https://iquilezles.org/articles/function2009/function2009.pdf